# Odoo : limit editable rows on editable tree

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

Suppose I have an editable tree

```
<tree editable="top">
    <field name="date">
    <field name="value">
</tree>
```

Now suppose I want to let the user edit the values for 3 most recent dates, but the others should remain readonly.

How would I do that ?

Comment: You should have huge knowledge on odoo JS backend to do something like that

Comment: Do you have a simple model that contains only two field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could add a boolen field to the model. which will be a computed field. based on that field you could apply the read-only attrs as following:

```py
class TheModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'The.Model'
    
    old_dated = fields.Boolean(compute='_old_dated_rec')
    date = fields.Date()
    value = fields.Integer()

    @api.model
    def _old_dated_rec(self):
        """define the condition of old dated records which could be as"""
        recent_rec = self.search([], order='date desc', limit=3)
        old_rec = self.search([('id', 'not in', recent_rec._ids)])
        old_rec.write({'old_dated': True})
```

Then you could apply a scheduler to run everyday calling such method

```xml
<field name="old_dated" invisible="1" />
<field name="date" attrs="{'readonly':[('the_boolen_field','=',True)]}"/>
```

in such way, the compute method will update the boolean field.

Comment: I didn't know how to make it work with @api.model, so I removed it and computed the flag on the records, and that works. Many thanks.